# Compare Two Arrays and give the not same values back

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

ive got two arrays in excel vba:

```
Array1 = Array("123", "456", "789", "101112", "131415")
Array2 = Array("789", "101112")
```

Now i want to cut the first array from the values that are shown in Array2. The result should look like this:

```
result = Array("123", "456", "131415")
```

Does someone has an idea how to manage this in vba?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Loop over the first array and use Application.Match() to check each element against the second array - put the no-match elements in a third array.

Comment: Also please review your past questions and consider accepting any answers which helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way is to use `Join` on `Array1`, loop `Array2` on this string using `Replace`, and then `Split` the string back into an array. Something like this:

```
Sub sRemoveArray()
    Dim Array1 As Variant
    Dim Array2 As Variant
    Dim strData As String
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    Array1 = Array("123", "456", "789", "101112", "131415")
    Array2 = Array("789", "101112")
    strData = "@" & Join(Array1, "@")       
    For lngLoop1 = LBound(Array2) To UBound(Array2)
        strData = Replace(strData, "@" & Array2(lngLoop1), "")
    Next lngLoop1
    If Left(strData, 1) = "@" Then strData = Mid(strData, 2)
    Array1 = Split(strData, "@")
End Sub
```

Regards,